# Does DOM API provide HTMLTitle Object that implements Node interface?

Tags: javascript, dom

Does DOM API provide HTMLTitle Object that implements Node interface?

document.title returns only string part of the title.

```
typeof(document.title)
"string"
```

While other properties like `document.head` is `HTMLHeadElement` object and `document.doctype` is `DocumentType` Object and both implements Node interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.title` represents the current document's title **string**. The interface of the element can be accessed through:

```
var tit = document.createElement('title')
```

[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is not the correct way to get the internal class name. Use [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Using_toString%28%29_to_detect_object_class) instead:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(tit);
// returns "[object HTMLTitleElement]"
```

Comment: @Praveen That's implementation-dependent. The `.toString()` method can be overridden. The `.toString()` method of an `HTMLAnchorElement`, for example, returns the value of the `href` property. The safest way is to use the method as mentioned in my answer. Another example: `"x".toString()` shows `x`, while `Object.prototype.toString.call("x")` shows `[object String]`.

Comment: @Praveen Yes, why do you ask?

Comment: Cool, i am 27, at your age i just started to use computers :)

Answer (score 2):

[document.title](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#document.title) gives you a string as stated.

If you want the title element just use `document.getElementsByTagName`

`var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]`